# How many triangles can be made?

Tags: algorithm

I have a sorted sequence of positive integers. How many triangles can be made using these numbers as the lengths of the sides (triangles can not be degenerate)? I have no idea other than checking all possibilities.

Comment: How does one make triangles from integers?

Comment: I have clarified your question. If I've done so incorrectly, please edit to correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea other than checking all possibilities.

Of course you check all possibilities - after all, you are required to count how many possibilities you have. It's a matter of *how* you check them. Going through all sets of thee is O(N<sup>3</sup>), which is probably too slow.

You can do it in O(N<sup>2</sup>*log<sub>2</sub>N) by observing that once you've picked two sides `A` and `B`, you can find the max length of the third one by binary-searching the sorted list for a position of `A+B`.

Comment: It seems that complexity will O(N^2), because C increases monotonically, and  we need at most N steps for C for every A